# How to pass values to a page while clicking on dynamically generated 'Link' in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `array` of elements (eg. urls_array) and using this `array` I dynamically create links to a page. How do I pass corresponding values from this `array` to the page(destination) while clicking on the dynamically created Links?

```
1 - Leftnav.js


class Leftnav extends React.Component {
  render() {

    var urls_array = [
      url1,
      url2,
      url3
    ] 

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <SideNavMenu title="Dynamically Generated">
            {
                urls_array.map(links => (
                <SideNavMenuItem key={links} element={Link} to="/singlepage" >{links.toString()}</SideNavMenuItem>
                ))
            }
        </SideNavMenu>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Leftnav;
```

The above code will create three links url1, url2 and url3 and when clicking any of these links we wil be redirected to a singlepage.

```
2 - singlepage.js

class singlepage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}    
export default singlepage;
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is while clicking on the `url1` I need (value of) `url1` in the singlepage, if I click on `url2` I'm expecting `url2` in the singlepage and so on.

Comment: you have to include your links, like `to={"/singlepage"+links.toString()}` and then if you are using react router then you can use `slug` to get that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the data in state inside `to`

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/singlepage",
    state: { links }
  }}
/>
```

and access in `singlepage` component using `this.props.location.state.links`

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks @tarzen when i console.log(this.props.location.state.links); in singlepage it says undefined

Comment: Thanks @tarzel chugh .. you are correct i did one typo that is why I got undefined message .. I'm marking this as accepted answer.

Comment: I was in process of you creating sandbox link. Great you figured out.

Comment: I appreciate one more input from you, once I'm inside the /singlepage and if I click the url again the the state value does not change. Is there any possibility to refactor it? or should i change the approach ?

Comment: I cannot answer without knowing the structure of components, but if you just want to re-render on url then wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/componentname`, state: { data: yourdata }}}></Link>
```